# Phylogenetic correlation test

Tags: r, correlation, phylogeny

I need to perform a correlation test (returning r, t and p.value) between two variables that accounts for a phylogenetic correlation structure between individuals. Is there any simple way to do that in R?

Answer (score 1):

From the `ape` package, specifically `?ape::pic` ("phylogenetically independent contrast"):

```
 library(ape)
 cat("((((Homo:0.21,Pongo:0.21):0.28,",
        "Macaca:0.49):0.13,Ateles:0.62):0.38,Galago:1.00);",
        file = "ex.tre", sep = "\n")
 tree.primates <- read.tree("ex.tre")
 X <- c(4.09434, 3.61092, 2.37024, 2.02815, -1.46968)
 Y <- c(4.74493, 3.33220, 3.36730, 2.89037, 2.30259)
 names(X) <- names(Y) <- c("Homo", "Pongo", "Macaca", "Ateles", "Galago")
 pic.X <- pic(X, tree.primates)
 pic.Y <- pic(Y, tree.primates)
 cor.test(pic.X, pic.Y)

 # Pearson's product-moment correlation
 # 
 # data:  pic.X and pic.Y
 # t = -0.85623, df = 2, p-value = 0.4821
 # alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
 # 95 percent confidence interval:
 # -0.9874751  0.8823934
 # sample estimates:
 # cor 
 # -0.5179156
```

If you're going to do much of this work you might want to get Paradis's [Analysis of Phylogenetics and Evolution with R](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461417422), and see the [phylogenetics task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Phylogenetics.html)

Comment: Indeed, PICs can be a good alternative. I also tried pgls models using the gls function in the "nlme" package.  But I'm not sure if the statistics returned by these models (slope t value and p.value) are equivalent to correlation tests and are independent of the coefficient estimations?

Comment: PICs are simplest. And not necessarily equivalent (why don't you try?)  If you had more specific ideas you could have included them in your original question ...

Comment: Another solution is presented here: http://blog.phytools.org/2017/08/pearson-correlation-with-phylogenetic.html